# Is this a blackhat SEO technique?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I have a site which has been developed completely in flash. Now the site owners do not want to shift to a more text/html based site. So am planning to create an alternative html/text based site which the googlebot will get redirected to. (By checking the useragent). My question is that is this allowed officially by google?

If not then how come there are many subscription based sites which display a different set of data to google compared to the users? Is that allowed?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've dealt with this exact scenario for a large ecommerce site and Google essentially ignored the site. Google considers it cloaking and addresses it directly [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355) and says:

> Cloaking refers to the practice of presenting different content or URLs to users and search engines. Serving up different results based on user agent may cause your site to be perceived as deceptive and removed from the Google index.

Instead, create an ADA compliant version of the website so that users with screen readers and  vision aids can use your web site. As long as there as link from your home page to your ADA compliant pages, Google will index them.

Answer (score 5):

The [official advice](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/07/best-uses-of-flash.html) seems to be: offer a visible link to a non-flash version of the site. Fooling the googlebot is a surefire way to get in trouble. And remember, Google results will link to the matching page! Do not make useless results.

Comment: i will be using PHP to check user agent and show the content. So the URL will be exactly the same. Is that fine?

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer is no.

Answer (score 5):

Google [already indexes flash content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html) so my suggestion would be to check how your site is being indexed. Maybe you don't have to do anything.

I don't think showing an alternate version of the site is good from a Google perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If you serve up your page with the exact same address, then you're probably fine.  For example, if you show 'http://www.somesite.com/' but direct googlebot to 'http://www.somesite.com/alt.htm', then Google might direct search users to alt.htm.  You don't want that, right?

Comment: i will be using PHP to check user agent and show the content. So the URL will be exactly the same. Is that fine?

Comment: This will constitute cloaking. You must allow Google to crawl the site naturally or you will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

This is called cloaking. I'm not sure what the effects of it are but it is certainly not whitehat. I am pretty sure Google is working on a way to crawl flash now so it might not even be a concern.

I'm assuming you're not really doing a redirect but instead a PHP import or something similar so it shows up as the same page. If you're actually redirecting then it's just going to index the other page like normal.

Some sites offer a different level of content -- they LIMIT the content, they don't offer alternative and additional content. This is done so it doesn't index unrelated things generally.